# How to extract the text after a hyphen in bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a string: `dev/2.0` or `dev/2.0-tymlez`. How can I extract the string after the last `-` hyphen in bash? If there is no `-`, then the variable should be empty else `tymlez` and I want to store the result in `$STRING`. After that I would like to check the variable with:

```
if [ -z "$STRING" ]
then
      echo "\$STRING is empty"
else
      echo "\$STRING is NOT empty"
fi
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against calling your variable `STRING`. All-uppercase variables are used by the system (e.g. `HOME`) or the shell itself (e.g. `PWD`, `RANDOM`).

That said, you could do something like

```
string='dev/2.0-tymlez'

case "$string" in
    *-*) string="${string##*-}";;
    *)   string='';;
esac
```

It's a bit clunky: It first checks whether there are any `-` at all, and if so, it removes the longest prefix matching `*-`; otherwise it just sets `string` to empty (because `*-` wouldn't have matched anything then).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will follow your recommendation about lowercase.  And your solution works well.

Comment: @PeterMueller I am glad you've solved your issue. I can see that you've asked 4 questions and haven't accepted a single one. Please take a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `=~` operator:

```
string="dev/2.0-tymlez"

[[ $string =~ -([^-]+)$ ]]; string=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

`BASH_REMATCH` is a special array where the matches from `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` are assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed`:

```
for string in "dev/2.0" "dev/2.0-1-2-3" "dev/2.0-tymlez"; do 
   string=$(sed 's/[^-]*[-]*//' <<< "${string}")
   echo "string=[${string}]"
done
```

Result

```
string=[]
string=[1-2-3]
string=[tymlez]
```